# How would REST handle this interation?

Tags: rest

I'm trying to understand REST better (probably not the only one :) )

So suppose this interactions between a client and a server:

```
client send login to SO.
client sends create SO thread with a question regarding REST architecture.
```

There's obviously a state between the two operations. Namely that you can't post before login in.

How would REST handle this?

What confuses me is that it says [everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) that REST is suppose to be stateless: using a uniform and predefined set of stateless operations

So how would it work in practice then?

P.S.

Here's another example:

```
client send question to SO
client send comment to the question from op 1.
```

There's state between 1 and 2 because you first need to have a question before making a comment on it.

Comment: The service can return results that can be used in a subsequent call.  State will be maintained by a calling side.

Comment: That's state between operation 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

When they say that REST is supposed to be stateless, it means the result of a api call shouldn't vary depending on the api calls preceding it. Keeping state across api calls restricts caching and is thus not considered RESTful.

In other words, you are supposed to send the authentication token (or other information that might change the response) with each and every request.

Comment: So my question remains: if there's no state between calls, how can the second call be made? Obviously, you can't post before login in.

Comment: The point is you shouldn't store user sessions and information that is specific to a request. The client is supposed to provide all that information using GET parameters or request headers.

Comment: You are supposed to send the authentication token (or information) with each and very request.

Comment: where do you get that tocken? From the first request. So that's state between request 1 and 2.

Comment: @JeniaIvanov : https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

Comment: @JeniaIvanov the idea of statelessness in REST is that the server does not maintain any state regarding the client between these interactions. In other words, the server does not keep track of the fact that the client is logged in. 

There's nothing in REST that requires the client itself to be stateless.

Answer (score 0):

Stateless means client session is not going to store on server side. 
Session information can be stored on client side so there would no dependency on server and any client can call any service that is on server side. So whereever client's state is required that need to pass everytime.
Here your each request on server would be stand alone request.